# how to put my github orgname & access token in this line "requests.get(url='https://api.github.com/users/' + orgname + '/repos?page={}'.format(page))"

Tags: python, github, github-api, secretsmanager

I am trying to run this python script made by trufflehog to use their open-source scanner for scanning all repo's of an account or organization at once.

Does anyone know how i  can put my orgname and access token in the url without messing up the rest?

```
 def get_org_repos(orgname, page):
    response = requests.get(url='https://api.github.com/users/' + orgname + '/repos?page={}'.format(page))
    json = response.json()
    if not json:
        return None
    for item in json:

        if item['fork'] == False:
            print('searching ' + item["html_url"])
            results = truffleHog.find_strings(item["html_url"], do_regex=True, custom_regexes=rules, do_entropy=False, max_depth=100000)
            for issue in results["foundIssues"]:
                d = loads(open(issue).read())
                d['github_url'] = "{}/blob/{}/{}".format(item["html_url"], d['commitHash'], d['path'])
                d['github_commit_url'] = "{}/commit/{}".format(item["html_url"], d['commitHash'])
                d['diff'] = d['diff'][0:200]
                d['printDiff'] = d['printDiff'][0:200]
                print(dumps(d, indent=4))
    get_org_repos(orgname, page + 1)
get_org_repos("insertOrgName", 1)
```

So far I have tried a few variations of things like

requests.get(url='https://api.github.com/users/myOrg/repos?access_token=xyz?page={}'.format(page))

Comment: You may want to look at the requests docs: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ You can pass much of what you are doing in as params within the function call rather than building it out directly as keyword args.

Comment: You should set the `Authentication` header like so: `Authenticatoin: token TOKEN-VALUE` instead of passing it in the URL.  This is much more secure, since it prevents any URL logging from including the secret.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would use f-strings to make it more readable, secondly I would pass in GET parameters using built in requests functionality.

```
params = {'page':page, 'access_token'=access_token}
def get_org_repos(orgname, page):
    response = requests.get(f'https://api.github.com/users/{orgname}/repos', params=params)
    json = response.json()
    if not json:
        return None
    for item in json:

        if item['fork'] == False:
            print('searching ' + item["html_url"])
            results = truffleHog.find_strings(item["html_url"], do_regex=True, custom_regexes=rules, do_entropy=False, max_depth=100000)
            for issue in results["foundIssues"]:
                d = loads(open(issue).read())
                d['github_url'] = f'{html_url}/blob/{commitHash}/{path}'
                d['github_commit_url'] = f'{html_url}/commit/{commitHash}'
                d['diff'] = d['diff'][0:200]
                d['printDiff'] = d['printDiff'][0:200]
                print(dumps(d, indent=4))
    get_org_repos(orgname, page + 1)
get_org_repos("insertOrgName", 1)
```